# Preposition with support

Tags: prepositions

> I was pretty sure that he would support me **for** changing the age-old and static structure of our organisation.

My book says it should be *in* instead of *for*, is it correct ? To my ears *for* sounds well.

Please don't vote this to close / duplicate, there are numerous threads on SE similar to this  but I  couldn't find any one which could clear my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

The noun *support* takes complements with *for*, designating what is supported.

> I was pretty sure of his support for me.

But the verb support is transitive: what is supported is designated by an object:

> I was pretty sure he would support me.
>   I was pretty sure he would support changing the structure.

An *in* preposition phrase in this context is a complement: its oblique (the object of the preposition) is 'selected' by *support* to designate an activity which (it is implied) is performed by both the subject and the object.

> He supports me in changing the structure = *Both he and I both act to change the structure*

A slightly different use, in which the activity itself is the object of *support*, does not imply participation by the subject:

> He supports changing the structure = *He encourages the idea or project of changing the structure*
>
> He supports my changing the structure = *He encourages my effort to change the structure*

The *for* PP in your version is not a complement—*for* is not 'selected' by *support* to express a specific semantic relationship. *For* will be understood here to express the reason why he supports me:

> He supports me for changing the structure.

This might be appropriate if (just for instance) I were a candidate to be the organisation's next CEO: he supports me because I succeeded in changing the structure.